# Print a Date with some text in a new File using Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm new to the Shell script.

I want to create a file using shell script and write a current date and time in that file. So i tried the below code. It is creating the Text file successfully and writing the text but not the date. I don't know what did i miss. Any help would be appreciated.

```
echo $(date) : New Log File Created > Output.txt
echo $(date) : Exiting the program >> Output.txt
```

It is just printing the output as is like

```
"$(date) : New Log File Created"
```

Comment: run with double quotes `echo "$(date) : New Log File Created" > Output.txt`

Comment: Please show us a minimal sample: the first line (`#!/` stuff) and a non-working echo line. `echo $(date) : New Log File Created` works here.

Comment: This is my full code in batch file. I havent include any other lines in that batch file.

Comment: All bash scripts require a Shebang, which tells which shell to use to run the script. The most common shebang is #!/bin/bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you will want to format the output of date if you want to use it in the filename. If not you can use standard date command. You can find date format explanations [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/05/date-command-examples/)

Here is a sample block of code to output the current date and time to a text file :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $(date +%F-%T) >> Output.txt
```

Here %F outputs the full date in the following format : YYYY-MM-DD

And %T outputs time in the following format : HH:MM:SS

If you want to add more text than just the date, you can use the `"` delimiter, to create a string as follow :

```
echo "$(date +%F-%T) Log output" >> Output.txt
```

Putting all the text in the string makes sure bash doesn't interpret what's inside the string as operators and delimiters.

EDIT : Screenshot for bash version :

[image: Bash version example]

Comment: Hi, I have created a batch file using your code. But it returns the output in the new file as "$(date +T) ". Even i tried it from Cmd Prompt, it return the ouput in the new file as "$(date +%F-%T) " This is the issue, i tried out all the things i found in this website. But it is just printing the text in the file. I dont know where did i miss.

Comment: Could you run type-a bash, see if you have multiples paths. If not, run which bash to make sure of it's executable full path, and then run --version on it. I added a screenshot in my answer to show you. Please provide the output of /bin/bash --version

Comment: Hi Dexirian, It worked. thanks for your help. Its my silly mistake. I corrected it.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. If this answer is satisfactory could you accept it? Thanks

Comment: Yes. I clicked the Up Arrow button. Is this the way to accept it.If not, please guide me

Comment: I did. Thanks Dexirian.

Comment: Pleasure my friend